# script PLSQL doesn't execute in c# but ok in oracle

Tags: c#, oraclecommand

I try to execute this script in C# :

```
declare

  NEW_PAP_OPERATOR_ID number;

  cursor cu_records_a_traiter is
    select *    
      from operator_dossier         d,
           pap_operator_verandering ov,
           pap_verandering          v
     where d.operator_id = ov.operator_id
     and v.cr_info = :v_cr_info;

begin

  for rec_cu in cu_records_a_traiter loop

    /* insert new record */

    INSERT INTO BOOD.PAP_OPERATOR
      (HOOFD_OF_NEVENACTIVITEIT)
    VALUES
      (rec_cu.HOOFD_OF_NEVENACTIVITEIT);

    SELECT BOOD.SEQ_PAP_OPERATOR_ID.CURRVAL
      into NEW_PAP_OPERATOR_ID
      FROM dual;

    /* update with new record*/

    UPDATE Bood.Pap_Operator_Verandering
       SET pap_operator_doel_id   = NEW_PAP_OPERATOR_ID,
           datum_wijziging        = Sysdate,
           gebruiker_wijziging_id = '-549'
     WHERE pap_operator_verandering_id = rec_cu.PAP_OPERATOR_VERANDERING_ID;
  end loop;
end;
```

No exception but the script is not running.
If I execute sql script without C#, it works.
I think there is a problem with currval NEW_PAP_OPERATOR_ID
For the moment I don't anything special for it in c #.

C# code :

```
try
 {
   OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("myScript", Connection);

   command.Parameters.Add("v_cr_info", OracleDbType.VarChar, changeRequest, ParameterDirection.Input);
   command.ExecuteNonQuery();

   transaction.Commit();
 }
catch (Exception)
 {
   transaction.Rollback();
   throw;
 }
finally
 {
   Connection.Close();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not showing PROC parameter and also you didn't specify your command is PROC

```
OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("myScript", Connection);
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```